# What's the correct way to close SQLite connection after making a request?

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I'm working on a Java desktop application integrated with SQLite db,I'm having an exception that says `[SQLITE_BUSY] The database file is locked (database is locked)`
. I've read a bit and found that I need to *release* the connection off the database file after each making request . What is the correct to do it ? suppose I have:

```
try{
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("Select * from users"); 
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
...
ps = connection.prepareStatement("Select * from employees");
rs = ps.executeQuery(); // raises SQLException mentioned above
...
}catch(SQLException ex){}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're catching SQLExceptions and reacting to it by:

- Tossing away the pertinent information about what went wrong.
- Continue, silently.

This is, in a word, **dangerous**. And that's putting it mildly.

If you can't handle an exception (logging it, is not handling it) - and note that almost all exceptions cannot be handled, the correct thing to do is to toss it onwards. Any method whose very essence inherently involves databases should be declared to `throws SQLException`. If the method's nature is more general than that, you should catch that SQLException but rethrow it as something else (e.g. `throw new RuntimeException("unhandled", e);` - that is the most bare bones body of a catch block when you don't know what to do and don't want to think about it too much).

Separate from that, the proper way to close things is to use try-with. Looks like this:

```
try (
  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
  PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("Select * from users"); 
  ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
) {

  // loop through rs here
  // do not call close() - there is no need.
}
// resources have been closed here, no matter how we exit the block.
// even if the code inside the block throws, or `return;`s.
```

If you do it as above, you won't get that 'locked' thing happening. Unless you are interacting with the db from multiple threads and each is acquiring locks, in which case this gets *much* more complicated.

Comment: Ok, but where to prepare the Select employees statement?

Comment: Same style. If you need _both_ queries at the same time (somewhat unlikely) add 2 more items to the `try ()` thing. If not, let the try close and do it all over again (including making the connection). If you want to do these things separately but in a single connection: a single `try(Connection con = ...) { X}` and at X, 2 separate nested try blocks for the PreparedStatement+ResultSet.